# Folder Names with Spaces in XCOPY doesn't work?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, xcopy

Working on a batch script that backs up various important folders on my PC, I have ran into a problem. I can't seem to copy folders that have a space in their name. If there is a sub-folder that has a space and it's parent doesn't, It works perfectly fine. I also seem to be having a problem where I have FULL permission to 'My Documents' folder, but XCOPY won't copy saying 'Access Denied'. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

Surround your source specification with quotation marks, as in

```
xcopy "c:\my documents\some folder\*.*" ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried that.. well, a little like this:
`xcopy "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents" "F:\New Folder" /S /E /I`
and it says 'Is this a file or directory'?
You answer directory and it errors..

Comment: [Echo](http://academic.evergreen.edu/projects/biophysics/technotes/program/batch.htm#echo) that string, and see if it corresponds to an actual folder on the computer.  XCopy requires a filespec for the source, not just a folder spec, as in `xcopy "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents" "F:\New Folder\*.*"` if you want to copy all files from that folder.  Notice the `*.*`.

Comment: You would think that would be the case... but when I use the *.* it says 'File Not Found'. :-

Comment: Did you Echo the string?  Is the resulting path point to an actual folder on the machine?

Comment: 'echo' simply means 'Write to console', it doesn't verify anything. It simply writes what you tell it to. So it's going to write it if it's a true path or not.. I think.

Comment: It will output the content of the `%USERPROFILE%` variable with the rest of the path.  You're overlooking something really obvious; how 'bout doing some basic troubleshooting?

Comment: oh.. it outputs `C:\Users\Sean Webber\My Documents`

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be using Windows 7 (or Vista). On those systems `My Documents` is a symbolic link that only exists for backwards compatibility and cannot be accessed by users. The actual location of your documents folder is `C:\Users\Sean Webber\Documents`. Change your script to

```
xcopy "%USERPROFILE%\Documents" "F:\New Folder" /s /e /i
```

Comment: Thank You! That did fix my problem! I don't know my Windows would be designed like that, but it works perfectly now :)

Comment: While this solves the OPs problem, it doesn't answer the question of how do you xcopy directories (in batch variables) with spaces.

Comment: @TadLewis You did notice the double quotes around both path specs, didn't you?